# How set global variable for all request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I set at run time a global variable that is visible for all request? After login user, I need to save the data of DB connection and connect to his database in all request (with a middleware). 
I just proved `$GLOBALS` of PHP and `app()->singleton()` of Laravel, but, in both case, after the request I lose the content of variable.Why?

And how can I resolve? I don't want put the db data to session or cache.

Comment: Why are you storing the database session? Are you having individual databases for each user or something? Is there a reason you aren't able to close the db connection and re-open it with every request?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that global variables are only set at runtime meaning that they aren't persistent between requests. Additionally database connections will expire after a certain amount of inactivity and if your code is depending on that connection staying live you will likely run into some issues.

Comment: You need to do a little reading on multi-tenant app structures... there is an interesting blog post on this... It uses eloquent scopes... Take a look, it might give you some idea on how to implement what you want... http://jkwl.io/application-architecture/2015/02/16/multi-tenancy-in-laravel5.html

Comment: @Blakethepatton Yes, each user has his database. At first my connection is set to server database, after user login i need to "switch" to his db until he log off.  I can close and re-open db connection, but when re-open it i need to know what's the db where user should connect.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not already stored on the users' object then I'd probably store the database connection info with the user. Then I'd write a middleware to create the connection if a user is logged in. Something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if ($request->user()) {
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', $user->dbUsername, $user->dbPassword, $user->dbName);
    $request->merge("connection" => $connection));
    return $next($request);
  }
  return redirect('login'); //the user isn't signed in
}
```

Then later in your code you would use this connection by:

```
$this->connection = $request->connection;
```

Do note that there's no error handling for if the new connection fails and I haven't tested the code. But this is probably enough code to get you started.